# Can I make the caps-lock setting stick, for external USB keyboard in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, keyboard, caps-lock

I have a Macbook Pro running Mountain Lion, and I frequently use an (external) Apple USB keyboard with it.  In the Keyboard sys prefs, I set the "caps lock" key to be "^ Control", for both "Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad" and "Apple Keyboard" (i.e., external).

When I unplug the external keyboard, and plug it in again, though, the "caps lock" key once again is a caps lock key.  I can set it back in the sys prefs, but it only lasts until I unplug it next.

I have a different Mac running 10.7, with the same caps lock setting, and when I unplug the external USB keyboard, the caps lock setting stays set.

Is this by design?  Is it a bug?  Is there a workaround?  Can I make Mountain Lion remember my caps lock setting somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It should stick even on Mountain Lion.

Two suggestions.

First, you might use [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/download.php) to validate your preferences.

Second, try deleting ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist and logging out and logging in again.

In either case, the pref file might be messed up and that could prevent it from being saved.